# CASE WHEN 'All'

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have an issue, within a stored procedure, that I cannot figure out. I need to have a case filter applied for 5 items, and if it is one specific item, I need it to return all previous 5 items.

Code goes something like this:

```
...
WHERE [dbo].[ID] = CASE @var
  WHEN 'a' THEN 0
  WHEN 'b' THEN 1
  WHEN 'c' THEN 2
  WHEN 'd' THEN 3
  WHEN 'e' THEN 4
  WHEN 'all' THEN -- return 0 through 4 as possible answers
END
```

Comment: Some more context might be helpful.

Comment: What do you mean by `return 0 through 4`? return a String with "01234" ? :) Sample expected output, please

Comment: I don't see how you could return 5 different values for case ELSE, your case statement can only return one value

Comment: How's ` WHEN 'a'` is supposed to work without an expression in the `CASE`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For `ALL` value you need to put  `[dbo].[ID] = [dbo].[ID]` condition

```
WHERE [dbo].[ID] = CASE  @var
  WHEN 'a' THEN 0
  WHEN 'b' THEN 1
  WHEN 'c' THEN 2
  WHEN 'd' THEN 3
  WHEN 'e' THEN 4
  WHEN 'all' THEN [dbo].[ID] 
END
```

Comment: Documentation says: `CASE WHEN Boolean_expression THEN result_expression`. There is no boolean expression there. You can take a look at the [official documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) for more information

Comment: @MostyMostacho As I said `I'm guessing the code from example is a psedocode` and as OP said `Code goes something like this` so it's not working code but idea how to solve it

Comment: It was as close as I can get to posting the actual code due to company policies...

Comment: `WHERE [dbo].[ID] = CASE @var
  WHEN 'a' THEN 0
  WHEN 'b' THEN 1
  WHEN 'c' THEN 2
  WHEN 'd' THEN 3
  WHEN 'e' THEN 4
  WHEN 'all' THEN [dbo].[ID] 
END`